# How can I create buttons like those on the Apple website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to create buttons like the ones on Apple's [main page](http://www.apple.com/the-beatles/)?

[image]

Can anyone help me get started or point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick from these [google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprites) Or search on your own for "CSS Sprites". The basic technique is you put all the various states and images in one graphic, and then you use the `:hover` pseudo slector to change the `background-position` declaration to move the background image to the coordinates that contain the proper state(s).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to prodigitalson suggestion (which is the way Apple does it), you could consider using current CSS 3 styles.

Gradients: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/
Text Shadows (for embosed text): http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html
Roundedc corners: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

etc.

Comment: Very true, but the look/feel of the primary site navigation is not usually a candidate for progressive enhancement and generally needs to be the same across the board. And if you have to make a fall back sprite anyhow, I would just skip the css3 for this instance, but thats me.